# .htaccess error when compile

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to make a fake url using htaccess.. I had already looking for all forum or tutorial to write a htaccess, but why I got error on deeper "/".. this is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^about-us content.php?id=1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^how-to-order content.php?id=2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^information content.php?id=3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact-us content.php?id=4 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^accessories product.php?category=1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^accessories/([^/]+) product.php?sub-category=$1 [NC]
```

When I try to type "http://www.beauty4easy.com/accessories".. It's normal that the back side is show the "product.php?category=1". But why when I want to access "http://www.beauty4easy.com/accessories/kalung" It redirect to "product.php?sub-category=kalung" But without css.. The design is blank, become white and there's no image or css..

Please help, thank you very much :)

Comment: actually it's still localhost, but I can't type localhost there x_x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using relative paths for your assets (images, css, etc.) like:

```
../images/some_image.jpg
```

When trying to resolve that url from for example `http://www.beauty4easy.com/accessories/kalung`, it would look for the assets in:

```
http://www.beauty4easy.com/accessories/images/...
```

One possible solution is to use absolute paths for your assets like:

```
/images/some_image.jpg
/css/styles.css
```